# Cocoa Touch - Dialogue boxes?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can i get a plain basic dialogue box in cocoa touch.seems so simple but I can figure it out...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [UIAlertView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) class. For example:

```
UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Something happened" 
     message:@"And here is some more information about what it is."
          delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[myAlert show];
[myAlert release];
```

Comment: If you're not familiar with all the Cocoa Touch UI elements, I'd recommend grabbing the Apple Sample project "UICatalog" http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Create an `NS Window` using the Interface Builder. In your appdelegate, open the window.

Comment: but I want it to look like this..
http://artoftheiphone.com/wp-content/uploads/FTP/GPush5.jpg

can i do that?

Comment: mcandre: Read the question and the tags. Cocoa Touch refers to the Cocoa frameworks on iOS, not on the Mac. NSWindow wouldn't really be the appropriate class in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is CFUserNotification. The advantage to UIAlertView is that it does not require you to link against UIKit.